# Multipule ajax calls in a loop not returning in the same order as called

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bellow is the code that gets a list from the database and then requests more data for each list item and draws a google chart for each item. everthing is working fine apart from the ajax calls for more data are not returning in the same order as the original list. the lists have different counts depending of how they are called but over twenty charts are draw. The database is large and suspect this is the main reason for the ajax request not returning in the same order.

How can I alter my code to stop another ajax call before the previous has returned

```
function getList(fueltype, Date1) {
    document.getElementById('charts').innerHTML = "";
    var sd = new Date(Date1);
    var y =  sd.getFullYear();
    var m = sd.getMonth();
    var d = sd.getDate();
    var ed = new Date(y,m,d+1,0,0,0,0);
    var startDate = formatDate(sd);
    var fuelsearch = '';
    var dbFile = '';
    var endDate = formatDate(ed);
    switch(fueltype){
      case 'Coal':
        fuelsearch = 'COAL';
        dbFile = 'getJSONdata.php';
        break;
      case 'CCGT':
        fuelsearch = 'CCGT';
        dbFile = 'getJSONdata.php';
        break;
      case 'Nuclear':
        fuelsearch = 'NUCLEAR';
        dbFile = 'getJSONdata.php';
        break;
      case 'OCGT':
        fuelsearch = 'OCGT';
        dbFile = 'getJSONdata.php';
        break;
      case 'Other':
        fuelsearch = 'OTHER';
        dbFile = 'getJSONdata.php';
        break;
      case 'Pump Storage':
        fuelsearch = 'PS';
        dbFile = 'getJSONdataWithMIL.php';
        break;
      case 'Wind':
        fuelsearch = 'WIND';
        dbFile = 'getJSONdata.php';
        break;
      case 'Non Pump Storage Hydro':
        fuelsearch = 'NPSHYD';
        dbFile = 'getJSONdata.php';
        break;
      default:
    }

    $.ajax({
      url:  "getBmuList.php",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        fuel: fuelsearch
      }
    }).done(function (listData) {

      // draw chart for each id
      listData.forEach(function (itemId) {
        //console.log(itemId);
        drawChart(itemId,startDate,endDate,dbFile);
      });

    }).fail(function (jq, text, errMsg) {
      console.log(text + ': ' + errMsg);
    });
 }

 // This function takes a bmu and gets data in JSON format and draws a google chart
function drawChart(itemId,startDate,endDate,dbFile) {
     var bmu = itemId.itemID;
      console.log(bmu);
  $.ajax({
    url: dbFile,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      Id: bmu,
      date1: startDate,
      date2: endDate
      }
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
     console.log(bmu);
    var sd = new Date(startDate);
    var y =  sd.getFullYear();
    var m = sd.getMonth();
    var d = sd.getDate();
    //console.log(sd);
    //console.log(new Date(y,m,d,0,0,0));
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var options = {
      title: bmu,
      width: 495,
      height: 300,
      series: {
        0: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1 },
        1: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1},
        2: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1},
        3: { lineWidth: 1, pointSize: 1.1}},
      hAxis: {
        textStyle:{fontSize: 10},
        format: 'HH:mm',
        minValue: new Date(y,m,d,0,0,0),
        maxValue: new Date(y,m,d+1,0,0,0),

        viewWindow:{
          min: new Date(y,m,d,0,0,0),
          max: new Date(y,m,d+1,0,0,0)
          },

      },
      vAxis: {
        textStyle:{fontSize: 10},
      },
      chartArea: {backgroundColor: '#fffff0'},
    };


    // create new div for chart
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "500px";
    div.style.height = "330px";
    div.style.float = "left";
    div.style.border  =  "thin solid #DCDCDC";
    div.id = itemId.itemID + "_div";
    container = document.getElementById('charts').appendChild(div);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);
    chart.draw(data, options);
    //google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', selectHandler);


  }).fail(function (jq, text, errMsg) {
    console.log(text + ': ' + errMsg);
  });

}
```

Comment: You should take a look at [`Promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: *How can I alter my code to `stop` another ajax call before the previous has returned*, do you mean `start` or `stop`?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: asynchronous calls are not synchronous so if order matters than you need to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous by nature so all request are triggered in sequence, but responses are attended as soon as they come back.

jQuery `$.ajax()` function has an *async* option you can set to false making it to become synchronous (returning data instead of passing to *success* callback or throwing instead of calling *error* one in case of error).

But this option is deprecated and will be removed soon so it is not a good idea to rely on that.

So you need to use some truly async pattern. And, in my opinion, promises are the best (they may be not supported in very old browsers but there are polyfills to support them if you need it.

That being said, your `drawChart()` function has a *not so good* pattern in it having that it does not do **just** what its name says (drawing a chart) but also **asynchronously** requesting the data so it will be a **very good** idea to separate those behaviours.

> Of course, you could simply make it to return a promise and chain all calls in a *waterfall* style so each request + drawing starts **after** previous finished. But if (as I think to understand) none of those requests alter the results of the others (you just are asking for rendering order) the only difference will be that your code will be **much more slow** than actulally needed.

...so your new `drawChart()` function will be just the anonymous function you provided as `.done()` callback in its inner `$.ajax()` call.

Next step will be to modify `.done()` callback of the `$.ajax()` call inside of `getList()` function this way:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
}).done(function(listData){
    Promise.all(
       listData.map(function(itemId) {
           return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
               // Code removed from your original drawChart() function
               var bmu = itemId.itemID;
               console.log(bmu);
               $.ajax({
                  ...
               })
               .done(resolve)
               .fail(reject);
           });
       })
    )
    .then(function(listDataArr){
        // Here all (concurrent) requests finished.
        // ...and their results are in right order in listDataArr.
        listDataArr.map(drawChart);
    })
    .catch(reject);
}).fail(...);
```

Hope it helps.

It's not *as best as possible approach* but I tried to do it as similar as possible to your code to make easier to understand what are minimal required changes.

**Edit:** On the other hand, I figure out you could to not exactly require render them in order and it could be enought to **place** them in that order even being rendered in random order.

If that's true, you have another simpler strategy that doesn't require the use of promises at all and, apart of needing less changes to your code, it is sligtly faster and, in my oppinion, provides better user experience:

It consists on simply create **and place** the containers **(synchronously)** for each chart **before** start requesting their data and rendering them.

For example:

```
var charts = $("#charts");
var containers = listData.map(function(itemId){
    return $("<div></div")
        .addClass(itemId+"_div")
        .appendTo(charts);
});
// Rendering process here.
```

You can use your original implementation with the only difference of addressing divs like below instead of creating new one each time:

```
var div = $("div."+itemId+".div);
```

…even, it would be better using containers array (or sligtly rewritting below code to produce an "itemId: container" object). But I leave it to your choice.

Comment: Been working through this but stuggling to get the chart data to the drawChart function from listDataArr.map(drawChart);. I need to get the json data into DataTable of the new function drawChart

Comment: I did'nt tested anything: I just tried to show some guidelines to help you in solving your problem. It could contain errors from myself or maybe you need to fix other issues too. If you continue struggling on that, edit your question to add your updated approach so we could analyze what is happening…

Comment: …on the other hand, casually I just edited my answes adding an "edit" section with a maybe not as polite, but simpler (in the meaning that it requires less changes to your original aproach) and, (in my oppinion) better user experience because it continue rendering things as soon as possible, but in the right position. Maybe you culd be iterested on trying it instead…

Comment: …also, answering your comment, `listDataArr.map(drawChart)` calls `drawChart()` for each *listDataArr* item passing that item as first parameter and it's position in the array as second (even function could not expect it). Remember that in my proposition, `drawChart()` is the unnamed function you pased as `.done()` callback of the `$.axax()` call inside the original `drawChart()` function that just expect single parameter. Also note, if you need to do somthing else, you always can call anothes (even inlina and/or unnamed) function that, lastly, calls `drawChart()` inside it.

Comment: Ah! Ok. I'm glad to know 

Answer (score 0):

Add `async: false` to your `ajax` call.

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like so,

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url'
    success: function (result) {
        // Do Stuff
    },
    async: false
});
```

Please not the the use of `async: false` is being deprecated. You are going to get some warnings in the browsers. If you don't want these warnings I suggest you re-evaluate your approach.

Also,
Cross-domain requests and `dataType: "jsonp"` requests do not support synchronous operation

In your case, it would look like this.

```
 $.ajax({
url: dbFile,
dataType: 'json',
data: {
    Id: bmu,
    date1: startDate,
    date2: endDate },
async: false
}).done(function (jsonData) {
  // Do Stuff
});
```

Comment: Why the down vote? I think it's a useful answer to not only OP, but others looking for an answer.

Comment: It's not helpful if downvote and not leave a reason. One upvote for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can only achieve this by having ajax call one after the other in each other callbacks.

Or

Add async: false property in the ajax call